# error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent(): event name: tinymceChange

Tags: magento

I want to configurer a product on admin Magento 2.3.0 and an error comes up. 
"error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent(): event name: tinymceChange error message: Cannot read property 'createRng' of undefined".

What can i do ?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible cause of this issue, Sometimes when you create a piece of content and then save and reload it from the database you will see some random characters like Â or ? are added to your content. When you see unusual characters like these in your content this is likely a character encoding issue.

One of the Possible solution which I know

Go to path: `lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js`

Comment out this line: `content = decodeURIComponent(content);`

I hope this will help, not sure whether it works for you or not but you should try this